# How to prevent Malicious user to take token from localStorage to call REST API

Tags: angular, angular5, local-storage, session-storage, stateless

This is more Conceptual Question - 
When we use SPA like Angular, We used Implicit Flow for the Authentication. In this flow, we stores the token either in localStorage or sessionStorage.

When we need to call any API, we used to pass that access token to that API to get the data or to POST the data.

**I have a question here -** 
What If any malicious user found that token, then he can make thousands of POST API Calls with some garbage data using postman or any other client.

**How can we avoid such a situation?**
Thanks in advance!!!!

I know the few things like REST API, can have CORS implemented to tackle this problem. 
When somebody calls API, we can check the ORIGIN Header.

***But I read that ORIGIN Header is also not Safe. Malicious user can easily set it through code and he can call API programmatically. So how to deal with such a conditions?***

Please see this below image for more details -

[Detailed Description of Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqTYB.png)

Comment: Use https, refresh the token frequently, implement some kind of a filter that would invalidate the token if there are too many requests per interval.

Comment: @maljukan - Thanks maljukan for your reply. We already implemented throttling in our REST API. But what if, someone posts some garbage data at the interval of 10 mins or so???

Comment: @sudarshan1933 you're shooting all over the place. what you're reffering in your comment has nothign to do with your question. it's the host that needs to mitigate [DDOS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). they have their tools. you should not and can not deal with DDOS in application level.

Answer (score 0):

Many SPA application supports JSON Web Token(JWT) token, usually user authentication will happen in Authorization Server which will return the JWT token. Using the JWT token, Front end application can send as part of Header Auth Token.

Usually token will be stored in the session/local storage to maintain the statefull session b/w client and server.

As client side framework doesn't provide more security. These Token validation needs to handle in backend.

1) Enable CORS, so only particular domain name (https://example.com) can you allowed to access the API using 'Access_control_allow_origin'.

2) If attacker steals the token, he will be accessing through another domain, which backend server can deny based on origin.

3) If you want more security, you can opt for Public/Private key Authentication, which will be more secured.

Comment: Thank you so much @Suresh Kumar Ariya

Comment: But I read that ORIGIN Header is also not Safe. Malicious user can easily set it through code and he can call API programmatically. So how to deal with such a conditions?

Comment: When we call any API to backend, there will be 2 request, 1st one is Options Request without response which will verify whether  Host/Origin is authorized. 2nd Request is the proper request with API response. Hacking this is very difficult.

Comment: If any attacker tries to access the API, 1st request (OPTION) request will fail, which will block the 2nd request.